# Toggle active class on link

Tags: javascript

Given a script that toggles between two classes, I'm also adding an active state to the currently selected link to set an underline to show active state. However, when clicking the link continuously, it keeps adding the active class, rather than toggling the class on and off. How can I get the active state to show when the link is clicked, and switch off and apply to the other link when the other link is clicked?

**JS**

```
const Terms = {
  bindEvents () {
this.enTrigger.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  this.langToggle(this.englishContent)
  this.enTrigger.classList.add('active')
    this.frTrigger.classList.remove('active')
})
this.frTrigger.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  this.langToggle(this.frenchContent)
  this.frTrigger.classList.add('active')
    this.enTrigger.classList.remove('active')
})
  },

  init () {
    this.englishContent = document.getElementById('english-terms')
    this.frenchContent = document.getElementById('french-terms')
    this.enTrigger = document.getElementById('en')
    this.frTrigger = document.getElementById('fr')
    this.bindEvents()
  },

  langToggle (id) {
    this.englishContent.style.display = 'none'
    this.frenchContent.style.display = 'none'
    id.style.display = 'block'
  }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  Terms.init()
})
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="terms-nav">
  <a id="en">English</a><a id="fr">French</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using something like this to toggle between the two classes. So when you click on one element, it adds the class to itself but removes it from the other one.
[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0985nyop/15/)

```
var english = document.getElementById('en');
var french = document.getElementById('fr');


english.addEventListener('click', function(){
    this.classList.add('active');
    french.classList.remove('active');
});

french.addEventListener('click', function(){
    this.classList.add('active');
    english.classList.remove('active');
});
```