# How do I add active/inactive class when click on list item?

Tags: javascript

```
<ul id="myList">
  <li class="top" data-pos="A">Text1</li>
  <li class="top" data-pos="B">Text2</li>
</ul>
```

Now I want to create a `JavaScript` function that will add active/inactive class, when click on it.

```
click (data-pos="A") add class active
click (data-pos="B") add class inactive
```

Expected Result After Click

```
<ul id="myList">
   <li class="top active"   data-pos="A">Text1</li>
   <li class="top inactive" data-pos="B">Text2</li>
</ul>
```

How can I do that? with `JavaScript`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Toggle active class on link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49633991/toggle-active-class-on-link)

Comment: Please clarify your question by [edit]: What items have you clicked on to get _expected result_: only Text1 or also Text2? Which class follows _initial state_ (neither active nor inactive)?

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```js
var myList = document.getElementById('myList')
/* We will add the click listener to the parent <ul> element! */
myList.addEventListener('click', e => {
  /* Create a loop and iterate over all of the <li> elements inside #myList */
  for (var i = 0; i < myList.children.length; i++) {
    var li = myList.children[i]
    if (li === e.target) {
      /*
       If the <li> inside the current loop matches our clicked element (e.target),
       append active class to it
      */
      li.classList.add('active')
    } else {
      /*. */
      li.classList.remove('active')
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.active {
  color: yellow;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<ul id="myList">
  <li>Item #1</li>
  <li>Item #2</li>
  <li>Item #3</li>
</ul>
```

Notice there is no need for `.inactive` class. Items will be inactive by default, and active if they have `.active` class.

EDIT: the other answers are also correct, but I think mine is better because there is only one event listener on the parent, instead of one for each children. You can read more about [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation).

Comment: 1. My four line CSS snippet is needed to show visually how the program is running. 2. I have embedded a runnable fiddle. 3. `forEach` is [not supported](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_nodelist_foreach) on `NodeList`s in IE11.

Comment: Your comment adds valuable info, especially #3. In regret to #2: Sorry, mobile SO didn't display the fiddle

Answer (score 1):

#### Pure JavaScript Solution

Give all your *li* elements an *event listener* waiting for the click event.
JQuerys function `closest()` would be very useful here. Because in this solution we assign to *nextSibling* or *previousSibling* we always have to check if *nextSibling* exist to identify if it is the first or second list element.

*We have the three cases:*

1. Initial no active or inactive class ***else** part in the function*
2. Element we clicked on has class active
3. Element we clicked on has class inactive

At it's initial click give the clicked element the class *active* and the other element the class *inactive*.
Then check if the clicked element has class *active* remove it and add *inactive* to its classlist. At the other element remove inactive from it's class list and add *active* the same applys vice versa.
*Note: Important to check if it's the next or the previous element*

```js
document.querySelectorAll('li').forEach((x) => {
  x.addEventListener('click', myFunction);
})



function myFunction() {
  if (this.classList.contains('active')) {
    this.classList.remove('active')
    this.classList.add('inactive')
    if (this.nextElementSibling === null || this.nextElementSibling === undefined) {
      this.previousElementSibling.classList.remove('inactive');
      this.previousElementSibling.classList.add('active');
    } else {
      this.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('inactive');
      this.nextElementSibling.classList.add('active');

    }



  } else if (this.classList.contains('inactive')) {
    this.classList.remove('inactive')
    this.classList.add('active')
    if (this.nextElementSibling === null || this.nextElementSibling === undefined) {
      this.previousElementSibling.classList.remove('active');
      this.previousElementSibling.classList.add('inactive');
    } else {
      this.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('active');
      this.nextElementSibling.classList.add('inactive');

    }


  } else {
    this.classList.add('active')

    if (this.nextElementSibling === null || this.nextElementSibling === undefined) {
      this.previousElementSibling.classList.add('inactive');
    } else {
      this.nextElementSibling.classList.add('inactive');

    }
  }


}
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.inactive {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<ul id="myList">
  <li class="top" data-pos="A">Text1</li>
  <li class="top" data-pos="B">Text2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: No this solution is without JQuery

Comment: @hc_dev yes ty for the hint, haven't realized it.

Answer (score 0):

[Jquery](https://jquery.com/) is not necesary but if  you want to use it here is the solution :

```js
$( "li" ).click(function() {
  $('#myList li').removeClass('active inactive');
  $('#myList li').addClass('inactive');
  $(this).removeClass( "inactive" );
  $(this).addClass( "active" );
});
```

```css
/* Just for style purposes */
.active {
  color: blue;
  background-color: #E3F2FD;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="myList">
  <li class="top" data-pos="A">Text1</li>
  <li class="top" data-pos="B">Text2</li>
  <li class="top" data-pos="C">Text3</li>
</ul>
```